# Pandas styleframe styling applies differently to first sheet than all subsequent sheets

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, styleframe

I am writing multiple sheets to an excel workbook with some formatting.  In general everything works, just the formatting is a little off.  The formatting works exactly as I want on the first sheet, but I am looping through multiple data sets and writing to a sheet for each one and the subsequent sheets have the formatting a little differently.

Basically what I tried to setup was header is centered everything else is left aligned.  On the first sheet its as expected, but subsequent sheet header and everything else is left aligned except for my rows that are `apply_style_by_indexes` which are now centered.  So its like the `apply_header_style` and `apply_style_by_indexes` swapped or something.

Im guessing its something to do with how im defining the different styles and applying them.

```
data_dict = {args.source_env: {}, args.target_env: {}, "compare": {}}
for app in uniq_apps:
    # set some vars

    #setup lists for pandas
    pd_app_inst = []
    pd_platforms = []
    pd_src_env = []
    pd_src_rel_type = []
    pd_src_version = []
    pd_tgt_env = []
    pd_tgt_rel_type = []
    pd_tgt_version = []
    pd_param = []
    pd_src_value = []
    pd_tgt_value = []
    pd_columns = ['AppInst','Platform','SrcEnv','SrcRelType','SrcVersion','TgtEnv','TgtRelType','TgtVersion','Param','SrcValue','TgtValue']
    write=False

    logger.info(f'Comparing config for {app}')
    if data_dict[args.source_env][app]["config"] and data_dict[args.target_env][app]["config"]:
        src_cfg = data_dict[args.source_env][app]["config"]
        tgt_cfg = data_dict[args.target_env][app]["config"]
        write=True

        # add some data to data_dict

    else:
        logger.info(f"The app instance {app} does not exist in one of the environments, nothing to compare so skipping")
        continue

    params = list(data_dict["compare"][app])
    params.sort()
    for param in params:
        pd_app_inst.append(app)
        pd_platforms.append(data_dict[args.source_env][app]["platform"])
        pd_src_env.append(args.source_env)
        pd_src_rel_type.append(data_dict[args.source_env][app]["rel_type"])
        pd_src_version.append(data_dict[args.source_env][app]["version"])
        pd_tgt_env.append(args.target_env)
        pd_tgt_rel_type.append(data_dict[args.target_env][app]["rel_type"])
        pd_tgt_version.append(data_dict[args.target_env][app]["version"])
        pd_param.append(param)
        pd_src_value.append(data_dict["compare"][app][param][0])
        pd_tgt_value.append(data_dict["compare"][app][param][1])

    df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(pd_app_inst,pd_platforms,pd_src_env,pd_src_rel_type,pd_src_version,pd_tgt_env,pd_tgt_rel_type,pd_tgt_version,pd_param,pd_src_value,pd_tgt_value)),columns=pd_columns)
    sf = StyleFrame(df)
    default_style = Styler(font_size=10, horizontal_alignment='left', wrap_text=False)
    sf = StyleFrame(df, styler_obj=default_style)
    header_style = Styler(bold=True, font_size=14, horizontal_alignment='center')
    sf.apply_headers_style(styler_obj=header_style)
    sf.apply_style_by_indexes(sf[sf['SrcValue'] != sf['TgtValue']], styler_obj=Styler(bg_color='yellow',font_size=10,horizontal_alignment='left',bold=True))
    sf.set_column_width(columns=['AppInst','Platform','SrcEnv','TgtEnv'], width=15)
    sf.set_column_width(columns=['SrcRelType','SrcVersion','TgtRelType','TgtVersion'], width=25)
    sf.set_column_width(columns=['Param'], width=65)
    sf.set_column_width(columns=['SrcValue','TgtValue'], width=80)
    sf.set_row_height(rows=sf.row_indexes, height=15)
    with pd.ExcelWriter(excel_file,mode='a') as writer:
        sf.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=app, freeze_panes=(1,0), index=False)
    logger.info(f'Comparison written to output file for {app}')
```

Comment: The provided code doesn't help to reproduce the issue as it only writes a single sheet.

Comment: i added a little more code, essentially looping through a list of application data sets to compare in each sheet.  if there are 5 applications to compare, there are 5 sheets.  the number of sheets being written is what i expect.

Comment: I suspect the issue is that you keep creating new `pd.ExcelWriter` in every iteration of the loop. Usually you should create a single writer, use it the loop and call `save()` on it after the loop. I'll try to check later.